# Why is Kafka server limited to 100K messages?

Tags: perl, apache-kafka

Got an out of the box Kafka server and have the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::Kafka::Producer;
use AnyEvent;

my $condvar     = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $producer    = Net::Kafka::Producer->new(
    'bootstrap.servers' => 'localhost:9092'
);

for (my $index = 1;;$index++) {
    my $msg = "message: " . $index;
    $producer->produce(
        payload => $msg,
        topic   => "tracked-coords"
    )->then(sub {
        my $delivery_report = shift;
        $condvar->send;
        print "Message successfully delivered with offset " . $delivery_report->{offset};
    }, sub {
        my $error = shift;
        $condvar->send;
        die "Unable to produce a message: " . $error->{error} . ", code: " . $error->{code};
    });

}
```

Why does the Kafka server stop at 100K messages?

**EDIT**

The server stops reporting that it is receiving messages. Also the consumer stops receiving messages

**EDIT**

Kafka server logs this (at the end)

```
message: 99998
message: 99999
message: 100000
[2022-03-21 14:43:30,597] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=tracked-coords-0] Wrote producer snapshot at offset 500000 with 0 producer ids in 15 ms. (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2022-03-21 14:43:30,598] INFO [Log partition=tracked-coords-0, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Rolled new log segment at offset 500000 in 18 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2022-03-21 14:43:30,599] INFO [Log partition=tracked-coords-0, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Deleting segment LogSegment(baseOffset=400000, size=2191596, lastModifiedTime=1647873685289, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1647873685290)) due to retention time 2000ms breach based on the largest record timestamp in the segment (kafka.log.Log)
[2022-03-21 14:43:30,610] INFO [Log partition=tracked-coords-0, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Incremented log start offset to 500000 due to segment deletion (kafka.log.Log)
[2022-03-21 14:44:30,610] INFO [Log partition=tracked-coords-0, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Deleting segment files LogSegment(baseOffset=400000, size=2191596, lastModifiedTime=1647873685289, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1647873685290)) (kafka.log.Log$)
[2022-03-21 14:44:30,612] INFO Deleted log /tmp/kafka-logs/tracked-coords-0/00000000000000400000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2022-03-21 14:44:30,612] INFO Deleted offset index /tmp/kafka-logs/tracked-coords-0/00000000000000400000.index.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2022-03-21 14:44:30,612] INFO Deleted time index /tmp/kafka-logs/tracked-coords-0/00000000000000400000.timeindex.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2022-03-21 14:44:30,613] INFO Deleted producer state snapshot /tmp/kafka-logs/tracked-coords-0/00000000000000400000.snapshot.deleted (kafka.log.SnapshotFile)
```

Here is the code for the consumer

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature qw( say );
use Net::Kafka::Consumer;
use AnyEvent;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $consumer    = Net::Kafka::Consumer->new(
    'bootstrap.servers'     => 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id'              => 'mock_data',
    'enable.auto.commit'    => 'true',
);

$consumer->subscribe( [ "tracked-coords"] );

while (1) {
  my $msg = $consumer->poll(1000);
  if ($msg) {
    $consumer->commit(); #_message(0, $msg);
    say "====================================================================";
    if ( $msg->err ) {
      say "Error: ", Net::Kafka::Error::to_string($err);
    } else {
      say $msg->payload;
    }
  }
}
```

And the consumer stops at 100K

Comment: What do you mean exactly by “stop”? What error message is shown?

Comment: Producers have a limited batch size. The broker itself shouldn't stop

Comment: "Server stops reporting"... Where? What logs are you looking at?

Comment: Why are your perl logs mixed in with broker logs? I'm not familiar with perl, but you could try the same loop with kcat or built in producer bash scripts

Comment: @OneCricketeer - They are not mixed - the Kafka is run in a different terminal. Any good pointers to use  `kcat`

Comment: 1) I suggest not storing your kafka data under /tmp 2) start with the builtin `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh` script with over 100K records

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Thanks - I will give that a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Net::Kafka, which uses librdkafka library, maybe it's the **queue.buffering.max.messages** setting. That defaults to 100,000. Meaning:

> Maximum number of messages allowed on the producer queue. This queue
> is shared by all topics and partitions.
> See: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/html/md_CONFIGURATION.html

Try setting that to low number in probably your Net::Kafka::Producer->new() call to see if it cuts out sooner. That setting support 1-10M range. Oddly I don't see it in the Kafka server settings, so guess it's an edenhill driver setting only.